# How to print the line nuber that caused an exception in Java

Tags: exception, salesforce, try-catch-finally, apex

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm#exception_common_methods  This site shows that getLineNumber was included, but I am not able to use it. Thanks

( I am trying to locate a Null Pointer Exception )

Answer (score 5):

a `NullPointerException` stack trace includes a line number, so the exception should print it.

Comment: actually there was a java tag there when I answered, that you then removed.

Comment: actually Mr. Link edited the tags but I agree ;) And fundamentally the answer is correct also in apex world.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're asking, please show some code.

`getLineNumber()` and `getStackTraceString()` should include the line number (among others). Check https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008xc4IAA for sample message.

As for "how to print" - there's a try-catch example. Either simply push it at `System.debug()` or (if it's visualforce context) you can add a pagemessage.

You can also go to setup -> debug log, attach the tracking to your user and retry the action? You'll see the stacktrace and other goodies, line numbers next to the names of called methods...